# Trix Editor doesn't display in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I did follow Rails Guide [Installation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html)

Set up the form as below, but the trix editor doesn't display toolbar

1. @import "trix/dist/trix"; in `actiontext.scss`
2. import "trix",import "@rails/actiontext" in `packs/application.js`

Did I miss something?

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @answer, url: answers_path, :method => :post do do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Answer.rb**

```
class ExerciseAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

[The View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYjnN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put like this

```
packs/application.js
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```